# Interrogative sentence to declarative sentence

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, sentence

For example, convert "Where did Obama go to college" to "Obama go to college in where".

Is there any high-precision tools or paper about it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not an open tool for this. But, as you might already thought about this, you can parse the question, and with simple rules, make it declarative, although the rules might break in complicated cases.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to use the dependency parser and add rules to put the wh-word in declarative order, however it's not robust enough. It really seems to be a challenge to make it robust.

Comment: Agreed. It is indeed challenging. Unfortunately there is not a good way to evaluate the quality of the conversion....